# Retrieving values based on other values (dataframe) - how to make my code more efficient?

Tags: pandas

So after much trying I've managed to get something a bit closer to what I intend to do.

Scenario is as follows, a dataframe with many columns of which one contains unique values. Lets say this column is called "Customer Name". This maps with a one to many match on a different column lets call that one "Customer Alias".

I need a dictionary that for each customer name as a key has as value a list containing every possible customer alias for that customer name.

```
mapping_customers = {x:list() for x in data['Customer Name']}
for each in mapping_customers.keys():
    try:
         selection_rows = data.loc[data['Customer Name'] == each]
         mapping_customers[each].append(selection_rows['Customer Alias'])
    
    except Exception as err:
        
        print(err.args)
```

Right now the keys portion is working correctly but when appending the Customer Aliases they are not appended as individual items(strings) on a list. I basically get the Series in a list as the values in index position 0 and in index position 1, I see

```
'Series([], Name: Customer Alias, dtype: object)'
```

I would like to have each customer alias for a given customer name appear as an individual entry of that list.

Here is an example of what things would look like:

```
{'Great Customer': ['Great Customer LDA', 'Great Customer Enterprises','Great Customer Japan'],

'Best Customer': ['Best Offices', 'Best Customer LDA','BEST'],

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does data["Customer Alias"] contain lists of the aliases? If so you could do `mapping_customers = dict( zip( data["Customer Name"], data["Customer Alias"] ) )`.

Comment: Hi Leo, appreciate the suggestion but that doesn't quite work for what I need.  zip would collect one element from each "side" and the dictionary would then chuck away many of the keys since they must be unique. Also the value pair will typically contain multiple aliases.

Example of what one entry would look like

{'Great Customer' : ['Great Customer LDA', 'Great Customer Mexico', 'Great Customer Japan']}

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, and building on @Leo's answer, would this work?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer Name': ['Great Customer','Great Customer','Great Customer','Best Customer','Best Customer','Best Customer'],
'Customer Alias': ['Great Customer LDA', 'Great Customer Enterprises', 'Great Customer Japan', 'Best Offices', 'Best Customer LDA', 'BEST']})
dfg = df.groupby('Customer Name').agg(list)
dict( zip( dfg.index, dfg["Customer Alias"]))
```

output

```
{'Best Customer': ['Best Offices', 'Best Customer LDA', 'BEST'],
 'Great Customer': ['Great Customer LDA',
  'Great Customer Enterprises',
  'Great Customer Japan']}
```